# Installing Windows 7 on a Mac

Tags: windows-7, mac, macbook

For the longest while I've bee trying to install Windows 7 on a friends Mac but it just doesn't seem to work. I've tried to use Parallels desktop (which comes with XP) and a few other 3rd party apps but none seems to work for me.

What is the best app to choose and how can I install Win7 correctly?

Comment: Are you wanting to install it so you can virtualize it, or boot from it? Have you given Boot Camp a try yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling gives several guides on installing Windows 7 on parallels [including parallels's own site](http://www.parallels.com/products/upgrade-to-windows-7/). At what stage does your install fail?